# Is there a way to store and retrieve data locally in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am building a social media app where I have to store images data (Network images) locally.

I tried using local storage but am really confused how to implement it and retrieve data faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a database, you can use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to cache images see [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

or you can use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) to store anything you want.